# Returning the number of columns/longest row in 2D array and deleting a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, abstract-data-type

I am working on an assignment attempting to design two abstract data types in Python 3. My question is for the subclass "dnmMtx" I am looking for guidance on returning the number of columns along with the longest row in this subclasses "size" function and also trying to figure out how to delete a row. At  first I thought i could pop a row or use a .delete option but neither worked out. Also, currently my size function returns the how many rows there are. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

```
class DnmArr:

    def __init__(self):

        #create empty list
        self.arr=[]

    def __del__(self):
        print('Deconstructed')

    #return length
    def length(self):
        return len(self.arr)

    #append
    def append(self, x):
        #add x to arr
        if type(x) == int:
            self.arr.append(x)
        else:
            print('Not an integer.')

    #delete
    def delete(self,x):
        index = x
        #if element is present in array
        if index <= len(self.arr):
            self.arr.pop(index)
        else:
            print('Element does not exist.')


    def value(self, x):        
        if x <= len(self.arr) and type(x) == int:
            print(self.arr[x-1])
        else:
            print('Does not exist or list indices is not an integer')




#initializing subclass using parent
class DnmMtx(DnmArr):

    def __init__(self):
        DnmArr.__init__(self)
        self.arr=[[],[]] #creating 2d array

    def __del__(self):
        print('Deconstructed')

    def addrow(self):
        row = []
        self.arr.append(row)

    def delrow(self, x):
        if type(x) == int:
            self.arr.delete(arr[x])
        else:
            print('row does not exist/invalid row')

    def size(self):
         return len(self.arr)

    def append(self, x, y):
        if type(x) and type(y) == int:
            self.arr[x].append(y)
        else:
            print('Not an integer.')

    def delete(self, x, y):
        #if element is present
        if y <= len(self.arr[x]) and x <= len(self.arr): #check 
            self.arr[x].pop(y)
        else:
            print('Element does not exist.')

    def value(self, x, y):
        if x and y <= len(self.arr) and type(x) and type(y) == int:
            print(self.arr[x-1][y-1])
        else:
            print('Does not exist or list indices is not an integer')



#create object of type Dynamic Array
a = DnmArr()

b = DnmMtx()
```

Comment: And i have just realized my delete function is also flawed, It was working before i'm not sure what caused the error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.arr.pop(index)` call should work for rows too. The `list` has no idea that it's elements are also lists.

You can also delete a row in a list of lists by doing

```
del self.arr[row_index]
```

For example

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
del arr[0]
print(arr) # --> [[4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: ty i wasn't even aware that python had a del function like that